# What are the options for porting a Virtual PC image to a Mac?

Tags: virtualization, mac-osx, microsoft-virtual-server

I have a small website (around 30k hits per month) running in a VM on my Windows XP laptop. It's running under Microsoft Virtual Server R2.  It's actually working really well - haven't had any issues whatsoever.

I arrived at this solution since the web server died and it's not worth it for me to buy a new server, since this site is a hobby, not anything serious.

This is a temporary solution since I need my laptop back.

I'd like to migrate this VM to my Mac which is on all the time anyway.  But I don't see any server based solutions, only client-side ones like VMWare Fusion.

Is there any virtual solution out there that will run under a Mac and hopefully be able to read or convert my VM to its own format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider VirtualBox.  It's about as "server" as you get on a Mac

http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

I believe it can natively read the VHD files.

Comment: Yes, it does read VHD files natively, but it crashes when it does so.

Answer (score 1):

I agree fully with the [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) option, however to answer the question regarding server options, [Parrallels](http://www.parallels.com/) have a [Server](http://www.parallels.com/products/server/mac/) edition that runs on X-Serve. This is possible not a solution in this situation but an alternative non the less.